# Retrieve Kotlin Property type from Kotlin psi API

Tags: kotlin, reflection, compiler-construction, detekt

I'm trying to create new rule for [detekt project](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/issues/2701). To do this I have to know exact type of Kotlin property. For example, `val x: Int` has type `Int`.

Unfortunately, for property of type `private val a = 3` I receive the following:

1. `property.typeReference` is `null`
2. `property.typeParameters` is empty
3. `property.typeConstraints` is empty
4. `property.typeParameterList` is empty
5. `property.text` is `private val a = 3`
6. `property.node.children().joinToString()` has object notation of previous item
7. `property.delegate` is null
8. `property.getType(bindingContext)` is null (the property `bindingContext` is part of `KtTreeVisitorVoid` used

**Question**: how can I get name of type (or, what is better, object `KClass`) to compare the actual property type with `Boolean` class type? (e.g. I just need to get if property boolean of not)

Code:

```kotlin
    override fun visitProperty(property: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtProperty) {
        val type: String = ??? //property.typeReference?.text - doesn't work

        if(property.identifierName().startsWith("is") && type != "Boolean") {
            report(CodeSmell(
                issue,
                Entity.from(property),
                message = "Non-boolean properties shouldn't start with 'is' prefix. Actual type: $type")
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right solution:

```kotlin
fun getTypeName(parameter: KtCallableDeclaration): String? {
        return parameter.createTypeBindingForReturnType(bindingContext)
            ?.type
            ?.getJetTypeFqName(false)
    }
```

There are at least following values for Boolean type: `kotlin.Boolean` and `java.lang.Boolean`

Full [code is here](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/blob/f7c3987c68f1ad72b97e1eea370b10bbd1b01799/detekt-rules/src/main/kotlin/io/gitlab/arturbosch/detekt/rules/naming/IsPropertyNaming.kt).